# Taylor expansion with two variables

Tags: taylor-expansion

I just finished studying about Taylor expansion from a beautiful video by 3Blue1Brown on youtube. I was trying it out on a few questions until I came across this and I don't understand how to handle Taylor Expansion with multiple variable. Could someone help provide and explanation and the solution?

Q) Compute the first three terms of Taylor Expansion of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x) = ye^{x^2}$$

for $y\in\mathbb{R}$ around $x_0=0$. Please include intermediate steps.

Comment: Also the symbol $y$ is used, it's not a variable.  Notice the function is defined from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.  The $y$ is just a constant multiplying $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: PS Actual Taylor expansion with two variables is a much more involved process.  A function $f(x,y)$ has two first derivatives and four second derivatives (although two of them are usually the same).

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://pic.plover.com/MISC/symbols.pdf) to format your posts.  You will get a much more positive response if you questions are easy to read.

Comment: Oh yes you are right about y. I'm sorry.